# Is there a way in R to revalue within columns of listed dataframes?

Tags: r, list, rename

I have three data frames like this:

```
        Value Time Colour Fruit 
    1    9.0    1    Red Apple 
    2    9.5    2    Red Apple 
    3   10.0    3    Red Apple 
    4    9.0    1   Blue Apple 
    5    9.5    2   Blue Apple 
    6   10.0    3   Blue Apple 
    7    1.0    1    Red  Pear 
    8    2.0    2    Red  Pear 
    9    3.0    3    Red  Pear 
    10   2.0    1   Blue  Pear 
    11   1.0    2   Blue  Pear 
    12   3.0    3   Blue  Pear
```

They are listed in my_list:

```
my_list<- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
```

Now I would like to exchange the values of the "Fruit" column of all three data.frames in the list.
For the data.frames on their own I successfully used

```
library(plyr)

df1$Fruit <- revalue(df1$Fruit, c("Pear"="Banana", "Apple"="Mango"))
```

for changing one variable only in all data.frames I found the solution

```
rapply(my_list,function(x)     
  ifelse(x="Pear","Banana",x), how = "replace")
```

Any idea on how to work this through the list for two and more variables is appreciated. I would like to adjust the answer for almost 15 variables, so running single codes is not an option.

Comment: You can do: `lapply(my_list, function(x) dplyr::mutate(x, Fruit = plyr::revalue(Fruit, c("Pear"="Banana", "Apple"="Mango"))))`

Comment: Perfect, thank you Phil!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phil:

> lapply(my_list, function(x) dplyr::mutate(x, Fruit = plyr::revalue(Fruit, c("Pear"="Banana", "Apple"="Mango"))))